# Facing this error : "No overload for method 'ReadLine' takes 1 arguments"

Tags: c#, .net

hello guys i am new to c# programming but i was just try to take an input from the user by c# console application and save that info to an string array but its giving me an error

**Error 1   No overload for method 'ReadLine' takes 1 arguments**

```
namespace demo_try
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string[] sarry ={"hi -", "me"};

        //for (int i = 0; i < sarry.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.Write("- {0} -", sarry[i]);
        //}
        //foreach (var n in sarry)
        //{
        //    Console.Write("-{0}",n);

        //}

        string [] sarray= new string [10] ;

        for (int i = 0; i < sarray.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter the values for an array {0}", sarray[i]);
            Console.ReadLine(sarray[i]);
        }


    }
}
```

}

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'ReadLine' takes 1 argumentts
```

that would be great if you guys help me out in this matter :)

Comment: The error tells you pretty much everything you need to know. Look at the method signature and documentation for ReadLine.

Comment: check this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory. Read this documentation for reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You need to change your code to

```
sarray[i] = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: No it's not self explanatory. If it was, the question wouldn't have been asked.